# FileInfo throwing error regarding file

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
            string[] dfFileWildCards = Helper.DataFeedsWildCards.Split(',');
            string[] dfOriginalFilesPath = Directory.GetFiles(Helper.DataFeedsPath).Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date).ToArray();

            Helper.MyWriteLine("-->DataFeeds Folder: " + Helper.DataFeedsPath);
            Helper.MyWriteLine("-->WildCards: " + Helper.DataFeedsWildCards);
            Helper.MyWriteLine("-->There are " + dfOriginalFilesPath.Length + " files");

            foreach (string filePath in dfOriginalFilesPath)
            {
                Helper.MyWriteLine("Checking " + filePath.ToLower());
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath.ToLower());

                foreach (string dfFileWildCard in dfFileWildCards)
                {
                    if (
                        file.Replace(" ", "").Name.IndexOf(dfFileWildCard.Replace(" ", ""), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
                        &&
                        file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
                        )
                    {
                        filesToCopy.Add(filePath.ToLower());
                        Helper.MyWriteLine("---->Marked for copy " + file.Name + ".");
                    }
                }
            }
```

It is showing error in log for  d:\cnbrd\datafeeds\authorizeddatafeedfile_20121127.txt

```
11/28/2012 1:27:53 AM -->DataFeeds Folder: D:\CNBRD\DataFeeds
11/28/2012 1:27:53 AM -->WildCards: Inactive
11/28/2012 1:27:53 AM -->There are 7 files
11/28/2012 1:27:53 AM Checking d:\cnbrd\datafeeds\authorizeddatafeedfile_20121127.txt
11/28/2012 1:27:53 AM Exception occured: The path is not of a legal form.
```

Why is it so ?

Comment: Full exception stack and path that caused the error would be helpful.

Comment: When logging exceptions, always log the full stack trace (and all inner exceptions) using `ex.ToString()`, not just the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
file.Replace(" ", "").Name.IndexOf(dfFileWildCard.Replace(" ", ""), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
```

Should probably be:

```
file.Name.Replace(" ", "").IndexOf(dfFileWildCard.Replace(" ", ""), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
```

Notice I'm calling `Replace` on `file.Name`.

Comment: +1. Short repro: `System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@" ")` which called as part of `FileInfo.Replace(destination, backupName)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it is in this code block:

```
if (
    file.Replace(" ", "").Name.IndexOf(dfFileWildCard.Replace(" ", ""), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
    &&
    file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
    )
```

Since you are doing file.Replace(...) you are calling [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a3t4ek5.aspx) method, which actually replaces contents of files, and in this case, creating a backup file, which will fail since the specified backup file in "". I think you are trying to read the name of the file? If that is the case, then the following might be what you need.

```
if (
    file.Name.Replace(" ", "").Name.IndexOf(dfFileWildCard.Replace(" ", ""), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
    &&
    file.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
    )
```